# C# WPF Bind List of Classes with list to a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Say I have this:

```
public class MyObject
{
    int Node1 { get; set; };
    int Node2 { get; set; };
    int Node3 { get; set; };    
}
List<MyObject> Objects = new List<MyObject>();
```

So this I can easily bind to a datagrid just by setting it's ItemsSource property to Objects.

This is what I really want to bind to a datagrid:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public List<int> MyNodes{ get; set; } = new List<int>();               
}
List<MyObject> Objects = new List<MyObject>();
```

Can this be done? I can't get it to work...

Comment: So...you want to bind to `IEnumerable<IEnumerable>>` ?

Comment: Please show us what have you done so far with your XAML and what is the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type you want to send to `DataGrid`. If it is just enumerable of objects/ints, you can try to select sublists into one like this:

```
var allNodes = Objects.SelectMany (o => o.MyNodes).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks...tried...all it did was add empty rows to the datagrid.

Comment: Can you show how you bind it to DataGrid? ItemSource?

Comment: Oh...I just set the ItemsSource property to AllNodes.